# Difference between System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position and setCursorPos?

Tags: c#, winapi, cursor, mousemove

Is there any difference between

> System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position
>   and setCursorPos

Does the usage of one or other really affect the speed of mouse movement?
Thanks.

Comment: Odd question.  The speed of the cursor movement is either 0 and infinite when you use this.  The cursor moves instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position`, internally, just calls `SetCursorPos` from the Windows API (after doing a permissions check).  There should be no different in speed or functionality.

I would recommend using the Windows Forms version if you are working in C#.

In general, the Windows Forms API is a fairly thin wrapper around the native Windows API.  If there is a corresponding method, it (nearly always) just maps to the native Windows API.  When using Windows Forms, you should really only revert to P/Invoke when there isn't a managed version of the API available.